nested scss is not working with angular 18 with tailwind
I am trying to get nested scss to work but can't with angular.  Can someone take a look at my sample repo?
Here is my scss and I am expecting my card to have a green background.
SCSS
.card {
    @apply flex flex-col bg-neutral-700 border shadow-sm rounded-xl p-4 md:p-5 m-1 md:m-3 text-white;

    .primary {
        @apply bg-green-500;
    }

    .card-body {
        @apply flex flex-col -m-1.5 overflow-x-auto p-1.5 min-w-full align-middle overflow-hidden;
    }
}

HTML
<div class="card primary">  
  <div class="card-body">
      I should be green background
  </div>

</div>

https://github.com/rontran/angular-nested/tree/main

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Currently your SCSS converted to CSS is
.card {}
.card .primary {}
.card .card-body {}

You need to use the & operator to say "copy the content of the parent into this selector" :
.card {
  &.primary {}
  .card-body {}
}

That then gives
.card {}
.card.primary {}
.card .card-body {}


Please use the below code:
.card {
    @apply flex flex-col bg-neutral-700 border shadow-sm rounded-xl p-4 md:p-5 m-1 md:m-3 text-white;

    &.primary {
        @apply bg-green-500;
    }

    .card-body {
        @apply flex flex-col -m-1.5 overflow-x-auto p-1.5 min-w-full align-middle overflow-hidden;
    }
}


Please explain how this would solve the issue OP is experiencing.

I don't even see a difference from the code that the OP provided.

Using & tells SCSS to replace it with the parent selector, thus applying the .primary styles directly to the .card element when it also has the .primary class.

Please add all the details inside the answer
